# Unable to understand what is happening in this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, series

Here

```
class FPMCRecommender(ISeqRecommender): 
    def fit(self, train_data):
        self._declare(train_data)

        train_data_supervised = []

        for i, row in train_data.iterrows():
            print(row['user_id'])
            u = self.user_mapping[row['user_id']]
```

Now inside the entire code repository `self.user_mapping` is not defined anywhere even in the parent class `ISeqRecommender`  yet the code is running and returning some value (0,1..)

Now what is `u = self.user_mapping[row['user_id']]` line doing , i am unable to understand as even if i debug it is simply taking to some pandas `series.py` file .

Can someone explain this ?

Comment: Try to us object introspection: methods like : `dir([object])`, `help([object])` and also you can use the `inspect` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) to find more about `ISeqRecommender` class or `user_mapping`

Comment: try to use python debugger to browse around the code. try ipdb or pdb

Comment: Maybe ``self`` has an interesting ``__getattr__``? 
Try this code:       
class MyClass():
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            setattr(self, attr, {})
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)

i = MyClass()

i.d["key"] = 1

pint(i.d)

Comment: class FPMCRecommender(ISeqRecommender):
     def __init__(self, n_factor=32, learn_rate=0.01, regular=0.001, n_epoch=15, n_neg=10):
        super(FPMCRecommender, self).__init__()
        self.n_epoch = n_epoch